# Highlighting last data point in pandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have number of graphs similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2012-01-01','2013-02-22')
y = np.random.randn(len(dates))/365
Y = pd.Series(y, index=dates)
Y.plot()
```

[image]

The graph is great for showing the shape of the data, but I would like the latest value to stand out as well. I would like to highlight the last data point with a marker 'x' and with a different color.  Any idea how I can do this?

[image]

Have added Dan Allan's suggestion.  Works but I need something a bit more visible.  As seen below the x is hardly visible.  Any ideas?

Have added return of final answer to complete this.  Changed the x to a D for a diamond for better visibility and increased the size of the marker.

```
Y.tail(1).plot(style='rD',markersize=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your example to plot the last data point as a red X.

```
Y.tail(1).plot(style='rx')
```

Comment: Have added suggestion to original question. Works but I need something a bit more visible. As seen above the x is hardly visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Y.tail(1).plot(style='rx', markersize =15)

works even better just change the 15 for readable result

Comment: with some other data i get the following User Warning when using this code:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:2542: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
left=735015.0, right=735015.0
  + 'left=%s, right=%s') % (left, right))

trying to debug at moment

I also get some data where the single point moves to centre of plot look slike pandas plot does not like just overlaying another one

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with an example -data included - that reproduces this issue.